# Rspec not displaying colours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rspec

I'm running Rspec 2.0.0rc on Windows 7.  I am also running the win32console gem (1.3.0 x86-mingw32).

The colours aren't being displayed - everything is showing up in boring old white/grey.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I also tried Rspec 2.0.0. and had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted this out by uninstalling all the gems relating to RSpec and Win32Console.  Reinstalled (and specified 2.0.0 for RSpec) and everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

Under normall installation of rspec gems, you should get the colored output. I am not sure which version of gem you are using.

There is one more solution.

While running rspec give the command like this

```
spec --color  sometestfile.rb
```

--color options is important here

Comment: an, Thanks! That worked for me. How to make this option permanent so that one does not have to specify is everytime.

Answer (score 1):

RSpec 2 has been [officially released](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/10/10/rspec-200-is-released/) today, perhaps try upgrading?

Comment: I was actually running RSpec 2.0.0